# Calculate average from a list with duplicate entries

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have 2 google sheets I'm working off. The master and a copy to create a 'dashboard' for analytics.

**Master Sheet**

| name | quantity | price/quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| RozMo | 10 | 1.75 |
| Tam | 3 | 3.65 |
| Gurba | 36 | 12 |
| Tam | 30 | 0.55 |
| RozMo | 25 | 0.75 |
| RozMo | 5 | 0.50 |
| RozMo | 2 | 0.35 |
| Gurba | 150 | 8.75 |

**Dashboard Sheet** - *Desired Output*

| name | quantity | price/quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| RozMo | 42 | 0.939 |
| Tam | 33 | 0.831 |
| Gurba | 186 | 9.379 |

**Dashboard Sheet** - *This is how far I've got*

| name | quantity | price/quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| RozMo | 42 |  |
| Tam | 33 |  |
| Gurba | 186 |  |

**Formulae used**

*To get the unique names*

```
=UNIQUE('Master Sheet'!$A$2:$A)
```

*To get quantity*

```
=SUMIFS('Master Sheet'!$B$2:$B,'Master Sheet'!$A$2:$A,A2)
```

How do I populate the third column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See how this works for you (I cannot test it, since you did not provide access to the spreadsheet):

`=ArrayFormula(QUERY({'Master Sheet'!A2:C,'Master Sheet'!B2:B*'Master Sheet'!C2:C},"Select Col1, SUM(Col2), SUM(Col4)/SUM(Col2) WHERE Col1 Is Not Null GROUP BY Col1 LABEL Col1 'name', SUM(Col2) 'quantity', SUM(Col4)/SUM(Col2) 'price/qty' FORMAT SUM(Col4)/SUM(Col2) '0.000'"))`

This one formula *should* produce all headers and results, formatted according to your full "desired result." If not, share a link to your spreadsheet (or a copy of it).

Comment: Thank you for your response. What's Col4 about? Also, do I replace Col1, Col2... with A, B in the master spreadsheet? Thanks

Comment: You don't replace anything. The formula is written to work with the data you gave. Did it not work?

Comment: The virtual array (between the curly brackets `{  }` ) contains four columns: the original Col A, Col B and Col C from `Master Sheet` followed by a calculated fourth column (Col B x Col C from `Master Sheet`).

Comment: The formula should work as I provided it. If it doesn't, then there are factors in your spreadsheet that you didn't share in your post. Share a link to the spreadsheet (or to a copy of it), and I will take a look. That is the only way I can provide more than I already have.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. Well, I tried to get your formula to work but somehow messed it up. Hence, I'm sharing a subset of the data with the original headers and structure.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16mjEAHDWyXTLWDwF8EYsZSnqU-em3CLJIuh8yvB7uqY/edit?usp=sharing

Basically, I want to replicate the above only where 'trade type' header = 'buy'. This is another condition unfortunately which is why I thought to create that Master Sheet but looks like I can get to my dashboard without actually using the intermediate spreadsheet. Look forward to hearing from you. Thanks

Comment: Your updated request is very different from what you originally posted. It also goes beyond what a forum like this is designed to offer, as it constitutes customized, time-intensive work requiring an expert. That said, I've shared an additional solution with you in a new sheet ("Erik Help"), but I will have to leave it to you to analyze it for understanding. Please understand that I won't typically be able to invest that kind of time into a forum post, since I keep a full schedule of regular clients in addition to my work as a mentor, author and speaker. I trust what I shared works for you.